# What is the output of following?

Tags: python-3.x

Following is the code in python:

```
>>> print("abcdef".find("cd") == "cd" in "abcdef")
```

I think the output should be True, but it shows False. I want to know the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print("abcdef".find("cd") == "cd" in "abcdef")
False
>>> print("abcdef".find("cd"))
2
>>> print("cd" in "abcdef")
True
>>> print(2 == True)
False
>
```

> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
>
> Return the lowest index in the string
>   where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return
>   -1 if sub is not found.
>
> The find() method should be used only if you need to know the position of sub. To check if sub is a substring or
>   not, use the in operator:

```
>>> print(("abcdef".find("cd") != -1) == ("cd" in "abcdef"))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> "abcdef".find("cd")
2
> "cd" in "abcdef"
True
> 2 == True
False
```

"string".find() will return INDEX if string is found. Therefore you are getting int '2' as this is 3rd position in your given string.

Answer (score 0):

As shown next, `"abcdef".find("cd")` return the position of `cd` in `abcdef`, while `"cd" in "abcdef"` return if the first string can be found in the second string, the result is boolean. So the compare `==` will be false.

```
(base) C:\Users\nxa13855>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "abcdef".find("cd")
2
>>> "cd" in "abcdef"
True
>>>
```